# u torrent client crashes everytime a new torrent is added

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

I have been experiencing this problem for the last few days on my Windows 7 machine.

Whenever I try to add a new torrent for download on my u torrent client, it reports an application crash and exits creating a dump file.

Can you help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you have the latest version, or try the alpha/beta?.. It's available from the download page @ 
http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/win

.. just make sure uTorrent is closed (and from the tray); let us know.

**Edit**: If you go to the *%appdata%\uTorrent* folder, maybe do a little clean-up there as well (left-over torrent files, maybe removing .old files and if anything else)