# Bittorent and utorrent closes every time I switch it on

Tags: windows-7, bittorrent, utorrent

This problem has been occurring since the past few months,every time I try opening Bittorrent, it just opens for a few seconds and shuts off, I just have four downloads going on, they aren't active though. I installed utorrent and I tried, the problem was solved it was working fine until, I restarted my pc later and the same problem persists. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [u torrent client crashes everytime a new torrent is added](http://superuser.com/questions/726911/u-torrent-client-crashes-everytime-a-new-torrent-is-added)

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest another client, just to see if that's more reliable. Utorrent and Bitorrent are on the same codebase these days

Answer (score 0):

I would try looking at the Windows Event Viewer right after the crash occurs.  More than likely there's a problem that's being reported there and you can track it down by looking at the information available.

Start with `Application` and go down from there:

```
Windows Logs
| Application
| Security
| Setup
| System
| Forwarded Events
```

You can find Event Viewer in Administrative Tools.